# Forwarding a signed email with EWS fails with "Specified object was not found"

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mimekit

We have a service which forwards all emails incoming to Exchange server to particular team members. We have 2 issues with signed emails - extracting attachments from those mails and **forwarding these signed emails**. We've solved the problem with extracting attachments using [Mimekit](http://www.mimekit.net/) package.

When trying to forward a signed email with [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.forward) method, it fails with following error:

> The specified object was not found in the store. Cannot open
>   attachment.

Code looks like this, nothing really special there:

```
origMessage.Forward(Nothing, forwardToAddress)
```

**Is this a known issue with EWS?** Error referring to "opening attachment" makes me feel it thinks it should look for some attachments which actually do not exist - the only attachment present in the message is the signature `smime.7m`.

If the email is unsigned, the very same line executes just fine and it forwards the email successfully. Since we had a good success with solving the first mentioned issue with Mimekit, **could Mimekit be helpful also with forwarding signed emails?**

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to correctly forward the email, I've decided to "fake forward" it by basically sending a new message which looks the same. I suspect the issue is the presence of certificate data in the original mail which I'm not allowed to send forward. Newly created email (obviously) doesn't contain this certificate.

```
Private Shared Sub FakeForwardOfSignedEmail(ByRef origMail As EmailMessage, ByVal cc As String, ByRef attachments As List(Of Tuple(Of String, Byte())))
         Dim fakeForward = origMail.CreateForward()
         fakeForward.ToRecipients.Add(cc)
         fakeForward.Subject = "FW: " + origMail.Subject

         Dim body As New MessageBody
         body.Text = "<hr><b>From: </b>" + origMail.Sender.Name + " (" + origMail.Sender.Address + ")<br />"
         body.Text += "<b>Sent: </b>" + origMail.DateTimeSent.ToString + "<br />"
         body.Text += "<b>To: </b>" + origMail.ReceivedBy.Name + " (" + origMail.ReceivedBy.Address + ")<br />"
         body.Text += "<b>Subject: </b>" + origMail.Subject + "<br /><br />"
         body.Text += origMail.Body.ToString
         fakeForward.Body = body

         Dim forwardMsg As EmailMessage = fakeForward.Save()
         For Each att As Tuple(Of String, Byte()) In attachments
            forwardMsg.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(att.Item1, att.Item2)
         Next

         forwardMsg.Send()
      End Sub
```